# Replace array in object in JSON file with lowdb

Tags: javascript, json

I have been struggling with a task to update a JSON file. So far I could add new objects in certain arrays. But now I want to delete one. This is my code:

```
var index = request.body.index;
var items = db.get("users")
    .filter({ "authKey": request.body.authKey })
    .map("cart")
    .map("items")
    .value();

items.splice(index, 1);

var cart = {
    "items": items,
    "numbersOfItems": items.length
};

db.get("users")
    .assign({ items: items })
    .write();

// db.get("users")
//     .filter({"authKey": request.body.authKey})
//     .set("cart", cart)
//     .value();

// db.get("users")
//     .filter({"authKey": request.body.authKey})
//     .map("cart")
//     .assign("items", items)
//     .write();`
```

And the JSON is:

```
users : [{
  "username": "shop",
  "passHash": "something",
  "authKey": "something",
  "cart": {
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "Product 1",
        "price": 1000,
        "img": "url",
        "description": "Amazing! WOW!"
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

Comment: what's the problem here for you?

Comment: I want to remove Product 1 with this code but it does not work.

Comment: have you checked what's the value of `request.body.index` you get?

Comment: Yep, it is the correct index. The response.body is `{ authKey: 'NWTRssDxY_qrDpZvnB_eGWVfmlXzawWE+Cgu=KKbBvVVM-AUqGn%gdmC+=tu',
  index: 0 }
{ authKey: 'NWTRssDxY_qrDpZvnB_eGWVfmlXzawWE+Cgu=KKbBvVVM-AUqGn%gdmC+=tu',
  index: 6 }
`

Comment: Still no result.

Comment: in your code block, it's `request.body.index`, is this a typo? also your `response.body` seems to be an array

Comment: I am passing `var options = {
        authKey: window.localStorage.getItem("auth-key"),
        index: index
    };` as a body and no, `request.body.index` is correct. Why would be a typo and how did you know my response.body is an array.

Comment: Any other ideas?